# Pass data from one form to a specific cell in a datagridview from another form in C#

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview

I have a datagridview, dgv1, that has 5 columns namely: Credit, Debit, EntryDescription, AccountingEntry, Employee. since in the EntryDescription I may have to input several lines of text, what I did is make an event wherein when the EntryDescription is clicked, a new form with a richtextbox appears as ShowDialog and as soon as writing the description is done, user presses the AddDescription button and whatever texts that have been entered in the richtextbox should be added to the dgv1's current row and EntryDescription Cell. I have some codes crated already but I do not know to continue the rest. I Need your wisdom. Thanks.

I know clicking the EntryDescription and a dropdown textbox appears wherein I place the description is good and better way, but I do not know how to do it so I just settled with this.

**In the AccountingEntry Form**

```
public static int RowCount { get; set; }
    public static string DescriptionToAdd { get; set; }
private void dgv1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex != EntryDescription.Index) return;
        var bal = new AddAccountingEntryDescription
        {
            RowIndex = dgv1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
        };
        bal.ShowDialog();
    }
```

**In the AddAccountingEntryDescription Form**

```
public int RowIndex { get; set; }
 private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AccountingEntry.RowCount = RowIndex;
        AccountingEntry.DescriptionToAdd = txtDescriptionToAdd.Text;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't use `static` properties to pass values back to your original form. That's a bad idea. You need to pass a reference to the `AccountingEntry` form to the newly created `AddAccountingEntryDescription` in the same way you're passing in `RowIndex`. That way you can directly communicate back to the `AccountingEntry` form without using `static` properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple.  The text entry form doesn't have to know anything about the grid or even the other form.  All it has to do is expose the data via a public property.  After `ShowDialog` returns, the original form gets the data from that property and does whatever it wants with it.  If you want to put that text into a cell in the grid then do so just as you would any other time.

Comment: I don't know how to place the text into the datagridview at current row and at EntryDescription cell. The reason I created a 2 static properties in the AccountingEntryForm is so I can access that properties without creating a new instance of the AccountingEntryForm. I can pass the text fine but I do not know how to place it in the datagridview at a cell as soon as the text has been passed.

Comment: If you're pushing the data to the grid form from the data entry form then you're doing it wrong.  Change it.  The grid form should be pulling the data from the data entry form.  That is the only way to do it correctly.

Comment: As for putting the data into the grid, you set the `Value` property of the appropriate cell.  If you don;t already know that then you haven't really researched how to use a `DataGridView` properly.  You've already got access to the cell via the `CurrentCell` property of the grid.

Comment: Thanks for the Advise. I know how to put data into a grid. It's just that I do not know what will trigger the placement of the data into the datagrid. That is the reason I have the RowIndex variable; it is so I would know on what row I should place it and DescriptionToAdd so I can put these texts and its format inside the specific cell. I don't want to put a button just to add these texts into the datagrid at its specific row and cell. I want it to be automatic wherein, as soon as the AddAccountingEntryDescription form is closed, the data will be pasted into the specific cell.

Comment: I just changed the operation to     private void dgv1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex != EntryDescription.Index) return;
            //var bal = new AddAccountingEntryDescription
            //{
            //    RowIndex = dgv1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
            //};
            //bal.ShowDialog();
            dgv1.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
            dgv1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
            dgv1.Rows[0].Height = dgv1.RowTemplate.Height;
        }

Comment: That code is unreadable.  As for this: "I do not know what will trigger the placement of the data into the datagrid", I told exactly what will trigger it.  Perhaps read what I post and do what I say: "After ShowDialog returns ... put that text into a cell in the grid".

Comment: I just changed the operation to private void dgv1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) { if (e.ColumnIndex != EntryDescription.Index) return; //var bal = new AddAccountingEntryDescription //{ // RowIndex = dgv1.CurrentCell.RowIndex //}; //bal.ShowDialog(); dgv1.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True; dgv1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells; dgv1.Rows[0].Height = dgv1.RowTemplate.Height; }